# How to detect an ‘anomaly behaviour in an given time-series’ in R

Tags: r, time-series, anomaly-detection

I started my question with an example of my project. There is a given time series like this:

```
time.series<-ts(givenTimeseries)

>time.series
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 30 
Frequency = 1 
[1] -0.50357041  0.07432535 -0.37925161  0.26056630  0.15171174
-0.35031172  -0.36649716  0.14000322 0.37795507  
[10]  0.00750549  7.95364894  8.56700818  7.76231780  8.19017478    
8.24413875 8.04252573 7.93831217 8.11326764
[19]  8.21827370  7.94055840  8.09190969  8.22867848  8.23907259
8.11866837 7.60379873 8.08207021 8.11394475
```

when it plots , the behavior sounds like a step upward([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8VH7.jpg))My question is,in general whenever I received a time-series with different behaviors, how I can detect them automatically?(not with plotting and say OK, I see peak)

Comment: look for/remove outliers... for example with `tsclean()` or `tsoutliers()` from the `forecast`-package.

Comment: Thanks Wimpel, This technique works with step upward. When I have spurious time series it dose not detect the peak time.